# How to merge several rows into one row based on a column with specific value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this way:

```
item_id    revenue    month    year
1          10.0       01       2014
1          5.0        02       2013
1          6.0        04       2013
1          7.0        03       2013
2          2.0        01       2013
2          3.0        03       2013
3          5.0        04       2013
```

And I try to get the revenue of each item from January to March 2013 like following DataFrame:

```
item_it    revenue    year
1          12.0       2013
2          5.0        2013
3          0          2013
```

BUT, I am confused on how to implement it in Pandas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: March 2014 or March 2013?

Comment: Sorry, it should be March 2013 like the last DataFrame above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice first, *then* `groupby` and `reindex` to include `0` values.

```
month_start, month_end = 1, 3
year = 2013

res = df.loc[df['month'].between(month_start, month_end) & df['year'].eq(year)]\
        .groupby('item_id')['revenue'].sum()\
        .reindex(df['item_id'].unique()).fillna(0)\
        .reset_index('revenue').assign(year=year)

print(res)

   item_id  revenue  year
0        1     12.0  2013
1        2      5.0  2013
2        3      0.0  2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` first then `sum` method to get the desire output.

```
df.groupby(['year', 'item_id']).sum().reset_index().drop('month', axis=1).set_index('item_id')

         year  revenue
item_id               
1        2013     18.0
2        2013      5.0
3        2013      5.0
1        2014     10.0
```

Comment: the desired output in question has mistake, for year `2013` , summing up `revenue` give `18` instead of `12`